# php.net manual not make sense of class Scope Resolution Operator ::

Tags: php, class, object, scope, operator-keyword

trying to learn php and caught on another snagg

**Ok this is what they are saying on php.net below about the ::**

The Scope Resolution Operator (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) or in simpler terms, the double colon, is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class.

As of PHP 5.3.0, it's possible to reference the class using a variable. The variable's value can not be a keyword (e.g. self, parent and static).

When referencing these items from outside the class definition, use the name of the class.

```
class MyClass {
    const CONST_VALUE = 'A constant value';
}

$classname = 'MyClass'; 

echo $classname::CONST_VALUE;  

echo MyClass::CONST_VALUE;
?>
```

**now back to the above code**

```
$classname = 'MyClass';
```

THAT IS A VARIABLE ! BEING GIVEN A 'STRING' VALUE OF 'MyClass'!

```
echo $classname::CONST_VALUE;
```

SO HOW IS THIS LINE EVEN POSSIBLE! IT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH THAT CLASS!

THAT IS BASICALLY A SIMPLE VARIABLE WITH A STRING VARIABLE!
SO HOW DOES IT MAGICALLY GET THE POWER TO ACCESS THAT CLASS CONSTANT WITH ::?
ONLY THING SIMILAR I SEE IS THE STRING 'MyClass' buts in theory has no power to let that happen its just a string.

can someone explain because im having 100 snags a day im starting to think php was just made up as they went along its too many contradictory things in it.

Comment: please don't use capslock that much, it's impolite and makes you look. well - *unprofessional*

Comment: is this site for helping people when theyre trying to learn this stuff or...

Comment: actually, no, it isn't. SO is *not* a tutorial site or something similar. SO primarily exists to help you fix errors in your code that you don't find yourself. and it's not about discussin whether or not a certain language is good or bad... regardless, writing all in caps is still frowned upon in basically the complete internet.

Comment: anyway, i believe it's because php has a very, very lax typing, and `::` expects whatever is left of it to be a classname, so it is treated as such if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case these two lines are basically the same.

```
echo $classname::CONST_VALUE;  

echo MyClass::CONST_VALUE;
```

PHP tries to "cast" the string `"MyClass"` to a Class. If the class exists everything works like a charm.

Other example could be:

```
$instance = new $classname;
```

where `$instance` is a valid instance of `MyClass`.

In other words you can replace class name with its string representation.

Comment: makes perfect sense thanks bro that is what i needed...glad this place has ppl like u who will take the time to help..this php stuff is powerful can change my life...do u do freelance php script work?...cause im working on a site and i need a simple search feature and at the time just cant figure it out